# Telerik Grid Ajax binding trouble in ASP.net MVC 3

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have a project using Telerik ASP.net MVC Grid. In MVC 2, everything works fine, including View in Ajax binding and partial View of grid in Ajax binding. But after upgrading to MVC 3, grid in partial View does not work in Ajax binding (control method in dataBinding.Ajax().Select() can not be invoked). However, grid in normal View works fine. I'd like to know what is the reason.

I know that in MVC 3, MicrosoftAjax.js, MicrosoftMvcAjax.js, MicrosoftMvcValidation.js and etc are obsolete. Their functions are replaced by jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js, jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js. But after I include them in the project, it still not works.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors?  Have you looked at what is happening with the http calls the grid should be making?  What version of jquery are you using?  What version of the grid?

Comment: There is no error I can see. Jquery is jquery-1.7.1.min.js and Telerik version is 2013.2.611. Jquery and Telerik js files are binded in Site.Master as     Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().Globalization(true).DefaultGroup(group => group
.Add("jquery-1.7.1.min.js")....Combined(true).Compress(true)

Comment: ok.  that all looks good.  have you used the browser developer tools or fiddler to see what is happening on the network when you load the page?  could you be loading multiple versions of jquery?  I'm currently using the grid with mvc5 and the ajax settings.  could you post some of your controller and view?

Comment: It only has one version of Jquery in the solution, and so I do not believe multiple jquery can be loaded. Please reference the code post in Answer. In Firebug after tab is clicked, what happen is that AthletesResults (specified in tab url '/Maintenance/AthletesResults/') can be invoked but Ajax binding action AthletesResultsAjax (specified in grid dataBinding.Ajax().Select) somehow can not be invoked in MVC 3. While in MVC 2, after AthletesResults is invoked, AthletesResultsAjax is automatically invoked to fill the data for the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the page, there are tabs that once is clicked, it will display a grid in partial View. The code is as follow,

```
Tab:
tabstrip.Add()
.Text(Shared.MaintenanceStrings.Tab_Results)
.HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "tab", url = "/Maintenance/AthletesResults/", tabNumber = "6" })
...
.ClientEvents(e => e.OnSelect("onTabSelect"))
.SelectedIndex(0)
...

function onTabSelect(e)
{         
var resourceId = $('#resourceId').val();
tabContentUrl = '/Maintenance/AthletesResults/' + resourceId;

$.ajax(
{
type: "POST",
url: tabContentUrl,
data: { id: resourceId, editable: 'true' },
success: function (data)
{
//reload the details content tab
$("#TabStrip-" + 6).html(data);
}                   
});
}

The grid to be displayed after tab is clicked,
Html.Telerik().Grid<MaintenanceAthletesResultsViewModel>()
.Name("Results")
...
.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
.Select("AthletesResultsAjax", "Maintenance")
.Update("UpdateAthletesResults", "Maintenance")
.Insert("InsertAthletesResults", "Maintenance")
.Delete("DeleteAthletesResults", "Maintenance")
)
.Pageable(paging => paging.PageSize(10))
.Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Height(290))
.EnableCustomBinding(true)
.Sortable()
.Filterable()
...

The controller action to go to after tap is clicked (Specified in url), 
public ActionResult AthletesResults(string id, bool editable)
{
this._resourceBL.PopulateMaintenanceResourcesViewData(ViewData, id, this.SelectedSport());

MaintenanceEditableViewModel model = new MaintenanceEditableViewModel { Editable = editable };
model.CurrentLanguageCode = this.CurrentLanguageCode();

return PartialView(model);
}

Grid Ajax Binding
[GridAction]
public ActionResult AthletesResultsAjax(string id)
{
List<MaintenanceAthletesResultsViewModel> model = null;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
{
model = this._resourceBL.GetMaintenanceAthletesResultsViewModel(int.Parse(id));
}

return View(new GridModel(model));
}
```